# Adding a vertically scrollable item inside a horizontal carousel

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm building a customised horizontal carousel, where in I want to display some items which are vertically scroll-able.

Code I've tried so far:

**html**

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="c-item">Item-1</div>
  <!-- to be displayed vertically -->
  <div class="abs">
    <div class="a-item">Abs Item-1.1</div>
    <div class="a-item">Abs Item-1.2</div>
    <div class="a-item">Abs Item-1.3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-item margin">Item-2</div>
  <!-- to be displayed vertically -->
  <div class="abs">
    <div class="a-item">Abs Item-2.1</div>
    <div class="a-item">Abs Item-2.2</div>
    <div class="a-item">Abs Item-2.3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="other">
  Other div
</div>
```

**css**

```
.carousel{
  color: #FFF;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: initial;
  .c-item{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35%;
    background: #000;
    height: 100px;
    &.margin{
      //margin-left: 35%;
    }
  }
  .abs{
    background: #444;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 35%;
    max-height: 180px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    .a-item{
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
  }
}
.other{
  background: yellow;
}
```

**Result**:

[image]

([codepen](https://codepen.io/shadowfax11/pen/ZEzVpWY))

The problem here is: I want the other div to start just below the item-1; meaning that the vertically scrolled div should be overlapping the other div and the carousel height should be fixed at 100px. I tried using `position: absolute` for the `.abs` div but then that div doesn't move on scrolling the carousel.

---

Desired output will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired result mean making the child overlap the parent, and i don't think that's possible. BUT you can "hack" this by wrapping the `.carousel` with another `div` (`.demo` it this general example), so the results will be something like this:

```css
.demo {overflow: visible; height: 100px;}
.carousel {
  color: #FFF;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: initial;
}
.carousel .c-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
  background: #000;
  height: 100px;
}
.carousel .abs {
  background: #444;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 35%;
  max-height: 180px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.carousel .abs .a-item {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.other {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="c-item">Item-1</div>
    <div class="abs">
      <div class="a-item">Abs Item-1.1</div>
      <div class="a-item">Abs Item-1.2</div>
      <div class="a-item">Abs Item-1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-item margin">Item-2</div>
    <div class="abs">
      <div class="a-item">Abs Item-2.1</div>
      <div class="a-item">Abs Item-2.2</div>
      <div class="a-item">Abs Item-2.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="other">
  Other div
</div>
```

As you can see from the snippet the scroll-x doesn't show - yet it exist. You can click one of the `.carousel` item and scroll them right and left.

Since it's not obvious that the `.carousel` is scrolling, you can add extra `buttons` to scroll it:

```css
.demo {overflow: visible; height: 100px;z-index: 3;}
.carousel {
  color: #FFF;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: initial;
}
.carousel .c-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
  background: #000;
  height: 100px;
}
.carousel .abs {
  background: #444;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 35%;
  max-height: 180px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.carousel .abs .a-item {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.other {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <button onclick="document.querySelectorAll('.carousel')[0].scrollLeft += 20;" style="position: fixed; top: 50%; right: 0;">L</button>
  <button onclick="document.querySelectorAll('.carousel')[0].scrollLeft -= 20;" style="position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 0;">R</button>
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="c-item">Item-1</div>
    <div class="abs">
      <div class="a-item">Abs Item-1.1</div>
      <div class="a-item">Abs Item-1.2</div>
      <div class="a-item">Abs Item-1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-item margin">Item-2</div>
    <div class="abs">
      <div class="a-item">Abs Item-2.1</div>
      <div class="a-item">Abs Item-2.2</div>
      <div class="a-item">Abs Item-2.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="other">
  Other div
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @SahilMittal have you checked this?

Answer (score 3):

### A flexbox solution

- Each item is **33.33%** wide and **100px** high. The *items* inside `.multiple` are also **100px** high.
- `.multiple` has `position: relative` and `overflow-y: auto`. The *items* inside have `position: absolute`.
- **Hint**: Container -> `position: relative`, items inside -> `position: absolute`. That's how it works.
- `top: (100 * n)px` for each `<div>` inside `.item.multiple`. `n` is the *index* of the `<div>` inside `.item.multiple`, starting with 0.

**The HTML structure has been changed**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: auto;
  color: white;
}

.carousel>.item {
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;
  //margin-right: 5px;
}

.carousel>.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: black;
}

.carousel>.item:nth-child(even) {
  background: darkgrey;
}

.carousel>.item,
.carousel>.item.multiple>div {
  height: 100px;
}

.carousel>.item.multiple {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.carousel>.item.multiple>div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel>.item.multiple>div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 100px;
}

.carousel>.item.multiple>div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 200px;
}


/* And so on ... 
.carousel>.item.multiple>div:nth-child(...) {}
*/
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item-1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item multiple">
    <div>Item-1.1</div>
    <div>Item-1.2</div>
    <div>Item-1.3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item-2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item multiple">
    <div>Item-2.1</div>
    <div>Item-2.2</div>
    <div>Item-2.3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="other">
  Other div
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution. Here I can see you're changing the items on click, but rather I want a *vertical scroll* (overlapping on the `other div`).

Comment: Still the scrolling div is not overlapping the other div. The scrolling div can contain some 10s of items so its height will be bigger, say 500px at least.

Comment: I've added the desired result in the updated question

Answer (score 1):

You have to play with `position` check snippet.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: auto;
  color: white;
}

.carousel>.item {
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;
  //margin-right: 5px;
}

.carousel>.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: black;
}

.carousel>.item:nth-child(even) {
  background: darkgrey;
}

.carousel>.item,
.carousel>.item.multiple>div {
  height: 100px;
}

.carousel>.item.multiple {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.carousel>.item.multiple>div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel>.item.multiple>div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 100px;
}

.carousel>.item.multiple>div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 200px;
}

.other {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  height: 117px;
}


/* And so on ... 
.carousel>.item.multiple>div:nth-child(...) {}
*/
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item-1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item multiple">
    <div>Item-1.1</div>
    <div>Item-1.2</div>
    <div>Item-1.3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item-2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item multiple">
    <div>Item-2.1</div>
    <div>Item-2.2</div>
    <div>Item-2.3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="other">
  Other div
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks good. Will check and get back to you

Comment: Hey, yes it worked for me. In fact both the solutions worked for me. But since the accepted answer was closer to my use case, I'm awarding the bounty there

Comment: Great.. as long as you got the solution SO rocks.